# @author в начале кода

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я в инстаграме подписан на некоторые паблики по пайтону и там время от времени выкладывают интересные коды по нему. Почти в каждом примере встречается данная запись

```
@author python.learning
'''Pass for example'''
import pymongo
...
```

Объясните, что это за `@author`, пробовал найти информацию в интернете, корректного ответа не нашёл

Comment: Не обижайтесь, пожалуйста, вопрос хороший, но первая мысль, которая пришла в голову: вот и выросло поколение, которое учится программировать в инстаграмме :)

Comment: @demonplus, нет-нет-нет, я не учусь в инстаграмме :D Я просто так подписан там, чтобы полистать ленту. Я учусь по книгам и статьям, просто заметил незнакомую вещь на картинке

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`epydoc` - Документирование исходного кода в самом коде с использованием аннотаций (аналог JavaDoc для Java)

http://epydoc.sourceforge.net

```
"""
@param x: This is a description of
    the parameter x to a function.
    Note that the description is
    indented four spaces.
@type x: This is a description of
    x's type.
@return: This is a description of
    the function's return value.

    It contains two paragraphs.
"""
```

Comment: Еще такую документацию можно легко сконвертировать в HTML

Comment: Т.е `@` это тот же `__doc__`? Просто мы делаем пометку автора?

Comment: `__author__` скорее